# Package_Resources does not exit; --no-vectors-version

Tags: android, exception, xamarin, build

i have th

Here are links to the discussions I've created:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/313641#Comment_313641

When I run the build project, I get a "Package_resource does not exit" error, using the diagnostic mode, I found the following log:

```
2>  Executing package -f -m -M obj\Release\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml -J C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\dnyestaj.yl2 --custom-package com.billakkspesialisten.bsordre -F obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources.bk -S obj\Release\res -S
    P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\0\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\2\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\3\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\6\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\8\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\9\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\10\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\11\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\12\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\19\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\22\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\23\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\24\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\25\jl\res -S P:\Work\Projects\gitApro\ebm2i\BLS_Proj\Droid\obj\Release\lp\29\jl\res -I C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --auto-add-overlay --no-version-vectors --max-res-version 26 (TaskId:428)
    2>Done executing task "Aapt". (TaskId:428)
    2>Task "Touch" (TaskId:429)
    2>  Task Parameter:Files=obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources (TaskId:429)
    2>P:\Программы\Visual Studio 17\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1921,3): error MSB3375: The file "obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.
    2>Done executing task "Touch" -- FAILED. (TaskId:429)
    2>Done building target "_CreateBaseApk" in project "Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:233)
```

Reading forms people say to pay attention to the very end of this line, the above:

```
--auto-add-overlay --no-version-vectors --max-res-version 26
```

Here is the .cspoj and package.config

DROID.CSPROJ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{94FF5F5E-391A-47D3-A94B-F15386E71732}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <AssemblyName>Droid</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Droid</RootNamespace>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.Designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v8.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>true</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>false</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AndHUD">
      <HintPath>..\Components\AndHUD.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FastAndroidCamera, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\FastAndroidCamera.2.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\FastAndroidCamera.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FortySevenDeg.SwipeListView">
      <HintPath>..\Components\FortySevenDeg.SwipeListView.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Java.Interop" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PullToRefresharp">
      <HintPath>..\Components\PullToRefresharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLite-net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\sqlite-net-pcl.1.4.118\lib\netstandard1.1\SQLite-net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a84b7dcfb1391f7f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.1.1.5\lib\MonoAndroid\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8226ea5df37bcae9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.1.1.5\lib\MonoAndroid\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.core.1.1.5\lib\MonoAndroid\SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e4ad490600e2234c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android.1.1.5\lib\MonoAndroid\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c301db686d0bd12, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android.1.1.5\lib\MonoAndroid\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core, Version=2.0.4.46, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="zxing.portable, Version=2.0.4.46, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\zxing.portable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ZXingNetMobile, Version=2.0.4.46, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ZXing.Net.Mobile.2.0.4.46\lib\MonoAndroid403\ZXingNetMobile.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Common\DatabaseResolver.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Common\ErrorMessages.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Common\Localize.cs" />
    <Compile Include="FragmentActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ImageActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PdfReader.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\ArticleCell.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\DatePickerDialogFragment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryFragmentPagerAdapter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryPage1Fragment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryPage2Fragment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryPageBaseFragment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryPageDayFragment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryPageMonthFragment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\History\HistoryPageWeekFragment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\InfoActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\LoginActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\ModalSdsTdsReadActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\ScannerActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\ScanSDSActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\SplashActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\UpdatedSDSActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\WelcomeActivity.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="GettingStarted.Xamarin" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\article_cell.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\FragmentActivity.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\history_1_fragment.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\history_2_fragment.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\history_cell.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\history_layout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\history_section.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\ImageActivity.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\info_layout.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\login_layout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\scanner_article_layout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\toolbar.axml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\welcome_layout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\ZxingOverlay.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\sds_scanner_layout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\updated_sds_layout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\updated_sds_cell.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\modal_sds_tds_read_layout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\Main.axml">
      <SubType>
      </SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\Strings.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_36dp.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj">
      <Project>{292eaef1-925b-4617-bd73-b88b8c48fda4}</Project>
      <Name>Core</Name>
      <IsAppExtension>false</IsAppExtension>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NewCore\NewCore.csproj">
      <Project>{3ccee225-40f3-4b9c-bb72-09997504a923}</Project>
      <Name>NewCore</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values-v21\theme.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\choice_selected.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\choice_unselected.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\date_field_rounded.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\ic_back.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\ic_info.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\ic_minus.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\ic_plus.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\Icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\logo.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\splash_screen.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\Icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\launcher.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\Icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\launcher.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\Icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\launcher.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xxhdpi\Icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xxhdpi\launcher.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xxxhdpi\Icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xxxhdpi\launcher.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\Colors.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\dimens.xml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\styles.xml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\theme.xml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values-nb\Strings.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values-sw600dp\dimens.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-mdpi\ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_36dp.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xhdpi\ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_36dp.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_36dp.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-xxxhdpi\ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_36dp.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\shape.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\notification_icon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\downloadIcon.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\round_button.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-v21\round_button.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\color\round_button_colors.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
```

...
      
        
          This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/issues/88

This is OneDrive files 1drv.ms/f/s!AhGZlSzHPlPygZZsWCRnVM57EG2jXA Sometimes an error is played during the Build, and sometimes when Deployed . I added the two corresponding OutputLog files.

Comment: Can you please upload your full [Diagnostic Build Output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output)? Please also include the Visual Studio version information.

Comment: This is OneDrive files https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhGZlSzHPlPygZZsWCRnVM57EG2jXA
Sometimes an error is played during the Build, and sometimes when Deployed . I added the two corresponding OutputLog files.

Yo can check Github, i open a new issue. There is more information: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/issues/88

Comment: See the comments here on how to further diagnose: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/301261/#Comment_301261

Comment: I already tried everything that is written there, but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found what my problem is. In my project there is a styles.xml file, it is he who generates the error "package_resources dos not exit".

My steps are to detect the error, if you can not find it (error) on the diagnostic output mod:

```
Create a new Android Project

Add Uses-Permission in Android Manifest Correctly

Add Packages :

+ 25.4.0.2 Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 
+ 25.4.0.2 Xamarin.Android.Support.v4  
+ 10.0.3   Newtonsoft.Json and etc packages 
    Warning: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. DroidPackageTest    
    Warning: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.  DroidPackageTest    
+ 2.3.2    ZXing.Net.Mobile
+ 1.4.118  sqlite-net-pcl and etc packages   
+          Core and NewCore dependensive
    Warning: No Address and User has been specified in order to establish a connection to a Mac Server, so only the main assembly was compiled for project 'Core'. Connect to a Mac Server and try again to build the full application. Core    

+ 1.2.0    AndHUD
+ 2.0.0.2  FortySevenDeg 
+ 1.0.2    PullToRefresharp  
Add Resources :

+ drawable in drawable
    Error: 1: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/white'). DroidPackageTest
        Resolve: add Colors.xml
+ Colors.xml in values
+ drawable-hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi in mipmap-hdpi...
    Error: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited  DroidPackageTest
    Warning: obj\Release\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black.png: libobj\Release\res\mipmpap-xhdpi\ic_keyboard_arrow_rightng warning: _black.png: libpng warniiCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile othat has bjb\een edited   DroidPackageTest
    Warning: 3 same warnings above
        Resolve: Download PNGoo from https://pngquant.org/; https://youtu.be/mfFrrIRtD24
+ other files from values in values
    Styles.xml generated an error "packages_resources does not found";
Styles.xml

    <!-- LAYOUTS -->   <style     name="Divider">     
       <item name="android:id">@+id/divider</item>     
       <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>     
       <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>     
       <item name="android:background">@color/lightgray</item>   
    </style>
```

I think the android:id invalid. I just comment

```
<item name="android:id">@+id/divider</item>
```

and everything worked , i'm very happy.